# Merging values from 2 CSS classes into 1 and sum up the margins and paddings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is in my client's project requirements. I am just giving example with `margin` only. if there are two CSS classes and have properties like.

**CSS**

```
.selector-1 {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.selector-2 {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="selector-1 selector-2">content</div>
```

We all know it will overwrite the properties from one class to another, but in this case, a client wants to add both `margin-top` and apply. So he is expecting **`margin-top:50px`**.

I know there is no way to do it in CSS.

Can anyone suggest something? I want to avoid using JS/jQuery. However, at the end, I can use, if it is possible to do it.

Comment: you can not do it  with pure css anyway!

Comment: There's quite a lot of answers below Sodhi, how did you get on with them?

Answer (score 0):

you can not do it with pure css anyway, because for do it you must get `margin-top` of classes and sum them.the problem is right here you can't access to another class through pure css.

but you can do it with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you:

`.selector-1.selector-2 { margin-top: 50px }`

Will give you 50px margin-top as both `.selector-1` and `.selector-2` margin-top's are combined to one margin-top called `.selector-1.selector-2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with pure `CSS`, so here is the solution with `jQuery` https://jsfiddle.net/z5pdt17j/1/

```js
$('body').append('<div class="selector-1 hidden" id="div1"></div><div class="selector-2 hidden" id="div2"></div>');

var tmargin = parseInt($('#div1').css('margin-top')) + parseInt($('#div2').css('margin-top'));

$('div#divTest').css({
 'margin-top': `${tmargin}px`
});

$('#div1 , #div2').remove();
```

```css
.selector-1 {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.selector-2 {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selector-1 selector-2" id="divTest">content</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this with jquery : easy solution

```
<div data-margin1="20" data-margin2="30" class="content">content</div>

(function(){
 let content = $('.content');
 let margin1 = content.data('margin1');
 let margin2 = content.data('margin2');
 content.css({'margin-top':margin1+margin2});
}())
```

Comment: that will allow client to input the two margins and then u can use them as u want mark answer if is that what u want XD